# What is this weird flying thing?

Tags: rage

There are these flying things hanging around the Ghost territory:

[image]

What are they? Do they have a use? Are they dangerous?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are Authority Drones.

Run into them with whatever vehicle you happen to be driving. Typically you'll have to look around for a ramp of some sort. You get some loot for doing so. There are 18 of them in total spread across the Wasteland. If you destroy all 18 of them, you can earn the Jumper Achievement/Trophy.